# Using an array to display a div element. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I know how to use css and html to make simple shapes appear but I would like to use arrays to display shapes; being that my next game project will include me having to duplicate shapes over and over again. My understanding of arrays is very weak, I've read everything on w3 and this is what I've been able to come up with so far in regards to displaying a simple line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="lineDiv"></p>

<script>
var line = {width: 2px, height: 7px, color: red};
lineArray[0] = line;
document.getElementById("lineDiv").innerHTML = lineArray[0];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1-My first question is why wont the line display?
2-My second question is what would I do if I wanted to generate more than one line when I figured out how to display the lines depending on which x/y axis I chose to display the lines at?

please do NOT include jquery on this answer, just use basic javaScript; i haven't even begun reading the jquery stuff on w3 yet.

Comment: Check your console, you will have an error similar to *"lineArray is not defined"*. What you want is `var lineArray = [ line ]`. You can then add more *lines* via `lineArray.push(anotherLine)`

Comment: So replace my "lineArray[0] = line;" with your "var lineArray = [line]"? and at that point the line will display?

Comment: Well, not exactly. It will most probably display `[object Object]`. Not sure if that's what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here

always use `var` to declare objects.

array elements aren't dynamically allocated in JavaScript, so use
`array.push`.

literal string values in JSON objects must be assigned using quotes,
single (`'1px'`) or double (`"1px"`).

use `JSON.stringify` to view JSON object data in the
browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="lineDiv"></p>

<script>
var line = {width: '2px', height: '7px', color: 'red'}; // set literal string values using quotes
var lineArray = []; //declare the array
lineArray.push(line); //add to the array
document.getElementById("lineDiv").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(lineArray[0]); //convert object to string
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

In order to render solid lines to the screen in `HTML`, you need to use the `Canvas`. This is a very small example, but it should be enough to help point you in the right direction. Sorry for not understanding your intent clearly before.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var main = function () {
                var c = document.getElementById('c'),
                    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
                    lineArray = [];
                lineArray.push({x: 10, y: 10, x2: 100, y2: 10, color: 'red'});
                lineArray.push({x: 10, y: 100, x2: 150, y2: 100, color: 'blue'});
                lineArray.push({x: 10, y: 150, x2: 200, y2: 150, color: 'green'});
                for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; ++i) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
                    ctx.moveTo(lineArray[i].x, lineArray[i].y);
                    ctx.lineTo(lineArray[i].x2, lineArray[i].y2);
                    ctx.strokeStyle = lineArray[i].color;
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
            };
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body onload="main()">
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very useful, but i was looking for a literal line, not the string describing the line. Very well put suggestion though.

Comment: For that you will need a graphics engine. Have you tried WebGL? It's very powerful.

Comment: Ive heard of it, but I figured for a single line It wouldn't be this hard to integrate an array.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you were trying to achieve. I've put together a small example of how to draw lines to an `HTML` canvas.

Comment: thank you, im going to digest this example, if i have any more questions ill hit you up! thx buddy

Comment: No problem. This is a very good resource. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_stroke.asp

Answer (score 1):

not entirely sure what you want to do but you need to use the style attribute to change the css

```js
document.getElementById("lineDiv").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("lineDiv").style.width = "100px";
document.getElementById("lineDiv").style.height = "7px";
```

```html
<body>
<div id="lineDiv"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: I 1 upd your comment, yes i'm familiar with how to make lines using css and html, was just wondering if i could integrate an array for design parameters

Comment: so first up, your example uses a dictionary.  You could place a span tag inside the div tag and then change the innerHTML of the span tag and use inline css with style="width:50%;"....... and get the innerHTML from your array/dictionary and some JS code